# how to read file from open file dialog and add to URL to play using wmplib?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am making a simple music player implementing the WMPlib to play media files ....
I am trying to open the file using a open file dialog ... the dialog comes and able to select the file but an exception comes when I try to assign the filename to  Player.URL

at the line

```
Player.URL = openFileDialog1.FileName;
```

the error says

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Can anyone please give me a clue on how to assign the filename to the player.URL

the complete code is as follows....

```
using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer Player;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }




        private void PlayFile(String url)
        {
            Player = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();
            Player.PlayStateChange +=
                new WMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEventHandler(Player_PlayStateChange);
            Player.MediaError +=
                new WMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_MediaErrorEventHandler(Player_MediaError);
            Player.URL = url;
            Player.controls.play();
        }

        private void Player_PlayStateChange(int NewState)
        {
            if ((WMPLib.WMPPlayState)NewState == WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsStopped)
            {
                this.Close();
            }
        }

        private void Player_MediaError(object pMediaObject)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot play media file.");
            this.Close();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            openFileDialog1.Filter = "(mp3,wav,mp4,mov,wmv,mpg)|*.mp3;*.wav;*.mp4;*.mov;*.wmv;*.mpg|all files|*.*";
            openFileDialog1.ShowDialog(); 



        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PlayFile(Player.URL);
        }

        private void openFileDialog1_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            Player.URL = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net

Comment: With that said, how about keeping a field in your class `private string  filename;` which you set in `button1_Click` as `filename = openFileDialog1.FileName;` and then read from in `openFileDialog1_FileOk` as `Player.URL = filename;`. Would that work for you?

Comment: the file path is being shown in the messagebox which is stored in openFileDialog1.FileName .... but I am not able to assign it to Player.URL

Comment: no that will give the same error

Comment: Then I guess `Player` hasn't been assigned. Would that be correct? Perhaps you could `new` that up in the constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you create an instance of *WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer* before using it. Right now it seems that you are clicking 'open file' button and trying to assign returned file name to null object.

Comment: WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer Player;

Comment: Yes, but you create an instance of it in PlayFile method. Also, use following construction: if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) { ... assign url to player ... }

Answer (score 1):

Try to use openFileDialog1 like this:

```
DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

if (result == DialogResult.OK)
{
   Player.URL = openFileDialog1.FileName;
}
```

in button1_Click()

Comment: please put break point at this line and tell me whats inside the "FileName" and "URL"

Comment: @Rishabh on what line does that error display? the first one or the `Player.URL...`?

Comment: on Player.URL = openFileDialog1.FileName;

Comment: replace this line "Player.URL = openFileDialog1.FileName" with "PlayFile(openFileDialog1.FileName)"

Comment: **please follow this link**: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383953(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: @Rishabh You need to tell us what object is `null`. Could you debug your application and check on what line you get the `NullReferenceException` and then what object is `null`?